# Can I replace multiple lines with a single line break?

Tags: key-bindings

A common operation for me is `V` `<movement commands>` `d` `k` `o` `ESC` to delete a bunch of lines and add a newline. Is there a quicker vim way to do this?

Comment: V <movement> c ESC ?

Comment: Also `ko` is (almost) always the same as `O`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I typically do the same: I think it's a fine pattern. Perhaps there's a way to achieve it with fewer keystrokes, but it probably has more "mental overhead" (you need to think more about what you're doing) so not sure if it will be faster/more convenient. A smarter way to do something in Vim isn't necessarily a *better* way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You could get it simply with:

```
<num>cc
```

From vim's `:help cc`

```
["x]cc          Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
            insert |linewise|.  If 'autoindent' is on, preserve
            the indent of the first line.
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

`0c<num>j`

`0`: go to the line start

`c`: prepare to replace

`<num>j`: move `<num>` lines down

Comment: @guntbert doubtful, C doesn’t take a motion (it’s the same as c$